# Can only Union of infinite subsets of Z or N be countable??

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I want to know whether there are any other sets beyond Z or N whose Union of infinite subsets can be a countable set. Clearly R don't qualify to be a countable set in the first place and so the union of their infinite subsets cannot considered to be a countable set.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is in fact countable.

Comment: Even the set of algebraic numbers (over $\mathbb Q$) is still countable.

Comment: Certainly any countable set $C$ has this property: the union of all infinite subsets of $C$ is itself a subset of $C$, hence countable. And no uncountable set $U$ has the property, since $U$ itself is one of the infinite subsets appearing in the union.

Comment: Even the set of [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here - if $A$ is infinite, the union of infinite subsets of $A$ is just ... all of $A$. *(And if $A$ is finite, that union is empty since $A$ has no infinite subsets in the first place.)* So you're just asking "are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ the only countable sets?", to which the answer is of course "no."

But maybe you meant the **set** of infinite subsets, not their union. In that case, $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ **don't** have this property - this is an easy corollary of the fact that [the powerset of an infinite set is uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).